# Is there a way of automating the process of refreshing profiles for XCode / XCodeBuild?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm setting up a CI build machine and wondering if there is anyway of making sure the machine always has an up to date set of profiles.

If a new device is added to the provisioning portal for example then the CI build will fail until Xcode 
/Organizer has its profiles refreshed.

Is there an XCodeBuild command for doing this so that I can automate it (within Jenkins)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer might be helpful, but I haven't implemented it yet:

[Command line Update of Provisioning Profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744959/command-line-update-of-provisioning-profiles)

For our system, I was just planning on putting the profiles into version control and then running those commands in a prebuild shell script.