# Bash: saving ls in an array -> receiving only small letters

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I try to save the ls of an directory in an array, which works out, but when i look in the array all names of the directories and files are in small letters.
What do I have to change, so that the names of files and dirs remain in their old notation ?
also files like "Picture of Dog.jpg" are 3 entries in the array: Picture, of, Dog.jpg
Is there a possibility to change that too ?

my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
currentDir="/home/marius/"
declare -l content=(` ls $currentDir `)
printf -- '%s ' "${content[@]}"
```

Comment: Once an question has been answered, don't edit it to ask a new question. Accept the given answer, and post a new question if necessary. anubhava's answer also solved your new question, by not using the output of `ls` to create the array.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884992/how-do-i-assign-ls-to-an-array-in-linux-bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884992/how-do-i-assign-ls-to-an-array-in-linux-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `declare -l` which by definition converts it to lowercase. As per `help declare`:

```
-l  to convert NAMEs to lower case on assignment
```

Just use this to create array without using `ls`:

```
declare -a content=("$currentDir"/*)
```

Comment: now every entry of the array is like

"/home/marius/Images//Picture of Dog.jpg"

how can i easily remove the "/home/marius/Images//" in the entire array ?

Comment: You can easily do: `cd "$currentDir"; declare -a content=( * )`