# Store filenames from linux "ls" command into separate array/list elements

Tags: linux, bash, unix

How do I store "just" the file names and their associated extension into an array or list in a "bash" script?  In a way that every filename is stored in a separate element WITHOUT other file information that ls spits out like the date created or the permission levels...

Comment: I prefer this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884992/how-do-i-assign-ls-to-an-array-in-linux-bash

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), just use something like `files=(*)`.

Answer (score 4):

I like to do:

```
filelist=`ls -1 /somedir/`
```

and then iterate over $filelist.

`ls -1` will only show the filenames without any of the other attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the great input.  How do you translate that in bash?  Sorry I'm new to linux and trying to learn my way through it.

Comment: I been using Linux and Unix - like systems since 1983, and I can't believe this is the first time I ever heard of this option.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
root@myserver-1-00:~# filelist=($(ls))
root@myserver-1-00:~# echo $filelist
Desktop
root@myserver-1-00:~# echo ${filelist[0]}
Desktop
root@myserver-1-00:~# echo ${filelist[1]}
Documents
root@myserver-1-00:~# echo ${filelist[2]}
Downloads
```

variable=($(yourcommand)) --> makes the output to be assigned as an array