# How do I select a random file from a directory?

Tags: bash

I have a directory full of random files. Some of them are pictures and end with `.png` extension. I want to create a bash script that deletes a random `.png` image every time I run it. How do I do this? Please explain your answer (or put appropriate links) since I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried something using the shuf command but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Something like `ls *.png | shuf -n 1 | xargs rm -v --`? Not really a good solution though

Comment: I'll just have to type that out in a terminal because I have no idea what xargs or even the '|'s mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `shuf` command to create a random shuffle and `head -1` to pick the top one

```
ls -1 *.png |  shuf | head -1
```

or

```
ls -1 *.png | shuf -n 1
```

Comment: what does the -1 in ls and shuf do?

Comment: `ls -1` list one file per line; `shuf -n 1` output 1 shuffled line

Comment: I tried the second one, and it gave me shuf: invalid line count: ‘-1’. I replaced the last - 1 with 1 and it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Using just `bash` builtins to pick the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
files=(*.png)
shopt -u nullglob
if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "No matching files!"
  exit
fi
file=${files[$((RANDOM % ${#files[@]}))]}
echo "Deleting $file"
rm -f "$file"
```

Adds all the matching files to an array (See [How do I assign ls to an array in linux bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18887210/9952196)), and then picks a random one from it using the `$RANDOM` variable (Which evaluates to a new random integer each time it appears) and some math.