# Using for in a Script, Ubuntu command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I pass each one of my repository files and to do something with them?

For instance, I want to make a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /myself
#for-loop that will select one by one all the files in /myself
#for each X file I will do this:
tar -cvfz X.tar.gz /myself2
```

Answer (score 0):

So a for loop in bash is similar to python's model (or maybe the other way around?).

The model goes "for instance in list":

```sh
for some_instance in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    echo "doing something with $some_instance"
done
```

To get a list of files in a directory, the quick and dirty way is to parse the output of `ls` and slurp it into an array, a-la `array=($(ls))`
To quick explain what's going on here to the best of my knowledge, assigning a variable to a space-delimited string surrounded with parens splits the string and turns it into a list.

Downside of parsing *ls* is that it doesn't take into account files with spaces in their names.  For that, I'll leave you with a [link to turning a directory's contents into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884992/how-do-i-assign-ls-to-an-array-in-linux-bash), the same place I lovingly :) ripped off the original `array=($(ls -d */))` command.

Comment: Hello! I have this in a Script: `for i in "${array=($(ls))"; do tar -cvfz "$i.tar.gz" done` but it does not work :o Even if I change `tar -cvfz i.tar.gz` with `echo $i` it prints nothing

Comment: Take it one step at a time. The line ```array=($(ls))``` should come the line before; it creates a variable named "array" which can be accessed in your for loop like ```for i in "${array[@]}"```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `while` loop, as it will take care of whole lines that include spaces as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /myself
ls|while read f
do
tar -cvfz "$f.tar.gz" "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way also.

for i in $(ls /myself/*)

do

tar -cvfz $f.tar.gz /myfile2

done