# Git Diff - How to find changed directories at top level

Tags: bash, git, github

I'm working with a list of file paths obtained from a `git diff` command, and I'm trying to extract the root-level folders from these paths. For example, I have a list like this:

```
.github/lint-checker/.eslintrc.js
Calendly/code/src/function-factory.ts
Calendly/code/src/functions/common/utils.ts
Calendly/code/src/functions/sync_calendar/main.ts
```

I want to extract the root-level folders so that the output is:

```
.github/lint-checker/
Calendly
```

I've tried using awk and sed, but I'm not getting the desired result. Can someone please provide a clear and concise way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can simply pipe your command to, e.g., `sed 's!\(.*/\).*!\1!'`.

Comment: Why is the second example `Calendly` and not `Calendly/code/src/`? Why aren't there four lines in the output since there are four different directories with changes?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I fully understand the question, but as described, this super crude and ugly code using bash parameter expansion gives the example output based on the example provided input.

`.github` is the root level folder in the first example, but you want the second folder in that case?

Putting the filenames in a bash array so I can demo an example...

```bash
filelist=(
.github/lint-checker/.eslintrc.js
Calendly/code/src/function-factory.ts
Calendly/code/src/functions/common/utils.ts
Calendly/code/src/functions/sync_calendar/main.ts
)
```

Iterate over the bash array and parse the output...

```bash
for f in "${filelist[@]}"; do
  [[ "${f:0:1}" =~ '.' ]] && echo ${f//${f##*/}} || echo ${f//${f#*/}}
done
```

Output:

```bash
.github/lint-checker/
Calendly/
Calendly/
Calendly/
```

Explanation:

`[[ "${f:0:1}" =~ '.' ]]` evaluates to true if the first character in the string is `.`, and false if not.

If the first character is a `.`, then `echo ${f//${f##*/}}` prints the value of `f` but after removing `${f##*/}` from the string. The value of `${f##*/}` is everything before the last `/` in the string, (i.e. `.github/lint-checker/`).

If the first character is not a `.`, then `echo ${f//${f#*/}}` prints the value of `f` but after removing `${f#*/}` from the string. The value of `${f#*/}` is everything before the first `/`.

If this is not what you are looking for, you can use `dirname`, `basename`, or other bash parameter expansion tricks to get what you need. Otherwise please provide the conditions where you want the "root folder" and where you want the "second-level" root folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since this question is tagged `bash`, `filelist` should be an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) instead of a string.

Comment: Good tip - thanks! I thought about using an array but my solution was a quick and dirty response to help answer the question or point in the general direction of answering it - and I was feeling too lazy to write out all the caveats and other complications with bash arrays or things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884992/how-do-i-assign-ls-to-an-array-in-linux-bash), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice/321757) or [this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a human-consumption diff try the core command, it's built to be scraped i.e. scripted:

```
git diff-tree @^ @ | awk '$1":"$2~/:04/' # only the toplevel diffs that changed a directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The `git` utility might have something for the output you want, but to give a solution to what you have now.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filelist=(
  .github/lint-checker/.eslintrc.js
  Calendly/code/src/function-factory.ts
  Calendly/code/src/functions/common/utils.ts
  Calendly/code/src/functions/sync_calendar/main.ts
)

uniq=()
declare -A path dotfile

for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
  case $file in
    (.*)
      dotfile["${file%/*}"]= ;;
    (*)
      path["${file%%/*}/"]=
  esac
  uniq=("${!dotfile[@]}" "${!path[@]}")
done
```

To check the output

```
declare -p uniq
```

```
printf '<%s>\n' "${uniq[@]}"
```

---

Saving the output of `git` directly using `mapfile` aka `readarray` ( which is a bashv4+ feature ).

```
mapfile -t filelist < <(git diff...)
```