# After set-key-partition-list codesign still prompts for key access

Tags: ios, macos, security, keychain, macos-sierra

I'm importing a `PEM` file containing public and private keys for my code signing identity with the following command:

```
security import "${PEM_FILE}" -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -T /usr/bin/codesign -T /usr/bin/security
```

On `OS X 10.11 El Capitan` I could then `codesign` without a prompt:

```
codesign --force --sign "${IDENTITY_HASH}" --timestamp=none `mktemp`
```

However, as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39868578/9636) have [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39868578/9636), `OS X 10.12 Sierra` now requires that you `set-key-partition-list` after `import`:

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "${PASSWORD}" ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

However, even after `set-key-partition-list`, I still get a UI dialog asking for permission to access my private key for code signing:

[image: "codesign wants to access key" dialog]

If I click `Always Allow`, then future `codesign` calls don't prompt, but I don't ever want that UI dialog to prompt. I want this all to be scriptable.

Why does `set-key-partition-list` work for other folks, and not for me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my original `import` command, I didn't supply a password for my keychain. If I supply a password to the `import` command, `set-key-partition-list` prevents the dialog from showing:

```
security import "${PEM_FILE}" -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P "${PASSWORD}" -T /usr/bin/codesign -T /usr/bin/security
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "${PASSWORD}" ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Then `codesign` doesn't show a dialog. It just works!

```
codesign --force --sign "${IDENTITY_HASH}" --timestamp=none `mktemp`
```

Comment: How do I get the `"${IDENTITY_HASH}"` for the `codesign` command? Sorry, I'm new to iOS development...

Comment: `security find-identity -v` will list all your identities. The `IDENTITY_HASH` is the 41-character hash listed first. You probably want one with a name starting with `iPhone Developer` or `iPhone Distribution` depending on whether you want to sign for development or distribution.

Comment: Heath Borders, I tried in my local system which is having xcode verison 9.0 and os mac high sierra 10.13, but still confirmation dialog popsup

Comment: I haven't tried it with Xcode 9 yet, and I'm not on High Sierra 10.13 yet.

Comment: Hey @HeathBorders, I don't understand your answer.  The `import` command's `-P` is the passphrase for the cert itself, not the password for the keychain.  If I enter the keychain password here, it will fail to import because my keychain and `.p12` file do not have the same password.

Comment: About -T; $ security import --help;  -T  Specify an application which may access the imported key (multiple -T options are allowed)