# Code Sign Failing from Jenkins for iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, codesign

I recently updated my Jenkins mac mini machine from yosemite to sierra along with latest xcode ( 8.3.2 ).

Now whenever I try to build my app and code sign from jenkins job, it fails with the following cryptic error

```
unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

When i ssh into my jenkins mac mini box as jenkins user and run the same build command everything works fine. Also, It works fine when building and signing the app from xcode. Has anyone seen this problem happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to the build step in Jenkins job solved the problem for me.

`security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k ${JENKINS_PWD} ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db`

Comment: This worked for me, but can you explain me as to what does this do? and some reference to further detail this?

Comment: You follow this answer and the whole post for more explanation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40039594/4634240

Comment: where should we need to this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's related to this open issue on Fastlane. You could start here:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8797