# Codesign on travis hangs build

Tags: travis-ci, keychain, macos-mojave, codesign

I am using Travis CI to automatise deploy process of my macos application.

So I have selected to run OSX Mojave 10.14 on travis VM.

In order to sign my application I have created custom keychain using these lines:

```
security create-keychain -p "password" $KEYCHAIN
security default-keychain -s $KEYCHAIN
security unlock-keychain -p "password" $KEYCHAIN
security import ${CERTIFICATE} -k ~/Library/Keychains/${KEYCHAIN} -P $PASS -A /usr/bin/codesign
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "password" $KEYCHAIN
```

However when I reach sign stage build hangs and I always see same error as output:

> No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
>   Check the details on how to adjust your build configuration on: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received

Has someone seen this error?

Could someone help me to understand what is going on? Or at least to tell me how to debug to see the problem. I have read that could be related to the fact that system is waiting for user to enter password but according to some post I have read line security-set-key-partition ... should fix that

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

your last line should read

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k "password" $KEYCHAIN
```

as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870033/1972627

hope that helps