# Jenkins script to sign Mac OS app requires entering admin user/password in GUI

Tags: macos, jenkins, code-signing-certificate

We recently had to get a new signing certificate for building our Mac OS application and installer.
I was able to update our scripts to use the new certificate - but now the Mac is prompting us IN THE GUI to enter the admin user/password for every use of the certificate (I think - 4 times with our current setup).

The prompt dialog says:

```
  macOS wants to make changes. Enter an administrator's name and password to allow this.  
  macOS wants to use the "System" keychain.
```

This is run as a Jenkins job, and before we updated the certificate, this didn't happen.  The scripts just ran and the app was signed.
This is running on Mac OS 10.15.7

What do I have to do to allow Jenkins to do the signing without asking for the admin userid/password every time? (especially since it's asking in the Mac GUI, which, normally, nobody is using.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.  The 2nd answer to this question worked for me:
[security / codesign in Sierra: Keychain ignores access control settings and UI-prompts for permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868578/security-codesign-in-sierra-keychain-ignores-access-control-settings-and-ui-p?rq=1)