# Codesign issue when Jenkins is used

Tags: ios, xamarin, jenkins, ant, codesign

If I build the iOS (part of a Xamarin.Forms project) with the Jenkins web GUI (directly running on the Mac) I get the following meaningful error from the console output:

> unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff

More detailed log

```
[exec] _CodesignNativeLibraries:
[exec]   CodesignNativeLibraries Task
[exec]     AppBundleDir: bin/iPhone/Release/AppiOS.app
[exec]     CodesignAllocate: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
[exec]     DisableTimestamp: False
[exec]     IntermediateOutputPath: obj/iPhone/Release/codesign
[exec]     Keychain: <null>
[exec]     SigningKey: XXX
[exec]     ExtraArgs: <null>
[exec] _CodesignAppBundle:
[exec]   Codesign Task
[exec]     CodesignAllocate: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
[exec]     DisableTimestamp: False
[exec]     Entitlements: obj/iPhone/Release/Entitlements.xcent
[exec]     Keychain: <null>
[exec]     Resources:
[exec]       bin/iPhone/Release/AppiOS.app
[exec]     ResourceRules: <null>
[exec]     SigningKey: XXX
[exec]     ExtraArgs: <null>
[exec]     IsAppExtension: False
[exec]   Tool /usr/bin/codesign execution started with arguments: -v --force --sign XXX --entitlements /Users/someuser/.jenkins/workspace/Project/ProjectName/ProjectName.iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/Entitlements.xcent /Users/someuser/.jenkins/workspace/Project/ProjectName/ProjectName.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/AppiOS.app
[exec] bin/iPhone/Release/AppiOS.app : error : /Users/someuser/.jenkins/workspace/Project/ProjectName/ProjectName.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/AppiOS.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff [/Users/someuser/.jenkins/workspace/Project/ProjectName/ProjectName.iOS/ProjectName.iOS.csproj]
```

On the other side it works without an error if I build

- in Xamarin Studio
- in Visual Studio for Mac
- while connected via Mac build host
- on terminal

After some research the [following solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111418/xamarin-forms-ios-error-replacing-existing-signature) were mentioned:

- allow access to keychain
- revoke and create new certificates/provisioning profiles

I tried both and I'm still getting the error. The question for me is, why Jenkins  launched with

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

can't access the certificates/provisioning profiles. This is the call from *Ant* in the configuration

```
<target name="buildIpa" depends="init" if="isMac">
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="${msibuild}" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="&quot;/p:Configuration=Release&quot; /p:Platform=&quot;iPhone&quot; /p:IpaPackageDir=&quot;./bin&quot; /t:Build ${TopLevelProject}.sln "/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

, where `msibuild` is `/Libary/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild`.

The other projects (Droid, UWP) are also build and I don't know how to only build for iOS ...

How can I find out if there is a signing error, an error with the installation of Jenkins or other error?

My current setup:

Mac OS X: 10.12.6
Xcode: 9.1
Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac: 7.2.2
Mono: 5.4.1.6
Xamarin.iOS: 11.3.0.47
Xamarin.Forms: 2.3.4.267
Xamarin Studio on Mac: 6.3
Jenkins: 2.73.3

Comment: Have you imported the certificate and provisioning profile to Jenkins? Did  Jenkins have full access to the signing files?

Comment: No, I only have imported/created the files directly on the Mac (which resides in the keychain). That is the question if Jenkins has full access. I did allow the access to the certificate for all applications, but this seems not enough.

Comment: Do you unlock the keychain in your build script using "security unlock-keychain -p keychainPassword pathToKeychain"?

Comment: @ChristopherStephan: No, currently not. Do I have to unlock that every time? What is `pathToKeychain`? */Users/someUser/Library/Keychains/*? Are there other options, which don't need to provide the password? Normally, it should ask me if I'd allow it and I click on *Always allow*, but that is never asked with Jenkins.

Comment: For example, `pathToKeychain` could be  /Users/someUser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db if the provisioning profile is stored in the login keychain. Currently I don't know a possibility to hide the password. There is a Jenkins plugin to import keychains, but it is not working with Mac OS Sierra any longer (https://github.com/SICSoftwareGmbH/kpp-management-plugin/issues/5). Try unlocking the keychain before you build the ipa. If it does not fix the problem create a demo app in Xcode, provide the bundle identifier you use for the app, add the provisioning profile and see if a build succeeds.

Answer (score 4):

what helps me

1. **Keychain**: moving certificates from Login to System and manually unlock it before Xcodebuild launch
   `security unlock-keychain -p "<YOUR PASS HERE>" ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`
2. **Custom xcodebuild arguments**: implement manual code signing style in Jenkins with CODE_SIGN_STYLE="Manual" and using Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Plugin (just easy to operate with env variables)

   CODE_SIGN_STYLE="Manual"
   PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=${PROVISIONING_PROFILE} 
   CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY}"
   -allowProvisioningUpdates

Comment: *"Moving certificates"*: Drag and drop in keychain? *"Custom xcodebuild arguments"*: Christopher above mentioned, that [KPP](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin) is not working anymore, is this also true for you? Do you need 1 and 2?

Comment: _Moving certificates_: Copy/Paste to System and delete from Login.
_Custom xcodebuild arguments_: **Keychains and Provisioning Profiles** its not for MacOSSierra, it's plugin for Jenkins, just for easy use keychain variables.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin

Answer (score 3):

When Jenkins is launched via launchd (controlled via the launchctl utility) the resulting process has reduced permissions to access resources in the system such as a given user's Keychain, because it is lacking an attribute set for a user who is actually logged in. You can work around this by having your Jenkins launched either via the JNLP or via an ssh slave. I suggest using the SSH slave option as the JNLP is fragile.

Here is Jenkins ssh slaves page:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin

These two stack overflows will give you more help on how to accomplish setting up your profiles via the command line:

[How to install developer certificate/private key and provisioning profile for iOS development via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369119/how-to-install-developer-certificate-private-key-and-provisioning-profile-for-io/5345966#5345966)

[security / codesign in Sierra: Keychain ignores access control settings and UI-prompts for permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868578/security-codesign-in-sierra-keychain-ignores-access-control-settings-and-ui-p)

Comment: Using an ssh session does not automatically resolve the problem. I'm explicitly calling security unlock-keychain as per @Pokemon answer, that solved it for me. Still, +1 for a very sensible explanation why running this through Jenkins caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Xamarin project with Automatic Provisioning setup. I could build locally on the Jenkins slave but not when running the same commands from our Jenkins Pipeline.

I found that I had to run and sh command before my build 
`sh 'security unlock-keychain -p "[Users Password]" /Users/[Users Name]/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db'` 
to be able to sign code.

It would seem that when run from Jenkins the shell environment has its keychains locked!